# iPhone and Android apps on Appcelerator Titanium or PhoneGap

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, sms, titanium

I have to create an application for iPhone/iPad and Android. It's pretty simple app. Here is a list of requirements:

- Login
- Getting the generated message from the server
- Getting contacts from the contact list of the phone
- Send the received message to selected contacts as SMS

It seems first three are good. What about 4 item? As I know I can't send SMS from iPad(it should not require jailbrake). It means I have to post message with the contact list back to the server and use any service to send the message out. Is there any another way?

Also, I have less than a week to build it all. I don't have experience in the mobile development so it would be good to use Titanium or PhoneGap.

Question: what would you suggest me to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert with phonegap but this is doable with Titanium. I created one app that sends SMS.

For sending SMS on iPhone and Android you'll need to use external modules, you can find many open source modules for sending short messages:

iOS:
https://github.com/omorandi/TiSMSDialog

Android:
https://github.com/omorandi/TiAndroidSMS

You may need a little experience in native languages if you got an error when building these modules.

For iPad (or all platforms) you may use some external commercial REST APIs for sending messages.

Comment: Thanks! Also I know iPad user can see SMS if he is logged in with apple account.

Comment: Also, what about compatibility? Can the created app work good on Android 2.3.X and 4.0.X? The same question for iPhone.

Comment: Yes sure the applications are compatible with Android 2.2 and above. iOS compatibility above 4.0 too.